# Integrating/Implementing NURBS-related calculations

Tags: computational-geometry, software, libraries, b-spline

Recently, I started to develop some codes that use NURBS (general things I intend to use/already using: spline generation, interpolation, grids, isolines, closest-point find, and many others), both for curves and surfaces.

The first practical problem I want to solve is to find a NURBS surface given a set of B-splines (Bezier patches, etc) in 3-D.

In one of the classic books about B-splines, [L. Piegl and W. Tiller, *The NURBS Book*, Springer, 1995](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642973857), Chapter 10 "Advanced Surface Construction techniques" describes a lot of computational algorithms, possibly including the ones I need (judging by the intro paragraph). However, I definitely do not want to invent the bicycle and would like to re-use as much as I can (provided the library development is not completely dead and has some userbase). I have no intention to write *yet another NURBS library*.

Right now, I am using [openNURBS](https://www.rhino3d.com/opennurbs) as a basic IO and storage format, but this library [supports only very basic operations](http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/opennurbs/what-is-opennurbs/#limitations) – and I am very reluctant to go into ["full Rhino mode"](http://developer.rhino3d.com/) to get access to the required functionality.

I already looked into:

- [SISL](https://github.com/SINTEF-Geometry/SISL), not entirely sure how I feel about the GNU license in this particular case.
- [libnurbs++](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libnurbs/) or [libnurbs++ GitHub](https://github.com/yiskang/libnurbs), the development seems to have stopped at least in 2013, possibly 2011.
- [Nurbana](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nurbana/), the development seemed to stop in 2003 (!)
- [verb](http://verbnurbs.com/), that I doubt I am the target audience of.
- and several other projects that lack any sort of documentation/development/user base.

So, I wonder, what are right now the common grounds for integrating **NURBS-related calculations** into your codes? Is there a widely used library that I missed (being relatively new to this topic)?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the topic. But have you checked OpenCascade?

Comment: @nicoguaro That’s one of the things I am looking into now. It’s just such a beast, I am reluctant to settle for it until I hear from other people with *similar needs* or I don’t have other more specific options. But that is a very good point, nicoguaro.

Comment: I would also check microelly's work on NURBS for FreeCAD (https://github.com/microelly2/freecad-nurbs), according to his demos in YouTube it seems useful.

Comment: @nicoguaro you want to briefly summarize OpenCascade + looking into FreeCAD's way of dealing with OpenCASCADE / NURBS as an answer? Don't want the bounty go to waste, and I think OpenCascade is the way to go...

Comment: Have you checked this [Python implementation](https://github.com/orbingol/NURBS-Python)?

Comment: @nicoguaro actually, I have not! thanks for the link, I have to take a very close look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should take a look to OpenCascade. It provides with Spline surfaces, and NURBS particularly. It is written in C++ and it is [released under LGPL license](http://git.dev.opencascade.org/gitweb/?p=occt.git).

Regarding FreeCAD, I don't think that they officially support NURBS, although you can import them (?). But there is a module [in development](https://github.com/microelly2/freecad-nurbs) (see also the [Forum](https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?t=16473)). The developer has published several [examples](https://www.youtube.com/user/microelly/videos) already.

I would also suggest to look  at [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) since it also [supports NURBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_(software)#Features).

Both, FreeCAD and Blender have rich Python API, that might be useful if you are a Python user.